# How to retrive data from Bluetooth when app in background iOS?

Tags: ios, background, widget, bluetooth-lowenergy, share

My scenario is:
Another (whatever app it is) try to retrieve the value from a Bluetooth device, But Bluetooth device doesn't send data other than our application.
Another application wants Bluetooth data it needs to call our app in background mode to perform an operation also in the background.
In short:
Retrieve data from Bluetooth in the background and share that content to another application.

If I tried using `Custom URL` it's open our application into the foreground. So, this one not covers our expectation.

Is that possible with `Widget` kind of? or any other method.

If any info missed let me know to understand my scenario.

Comment: This isn't possible. The app that wants the data needs to request it from the Bluetooth device directly. If the Bluetooth device can notify when the data is available then your app could write that to a data file that is shared though an app group, but this requires that both apps are written by the same vendor

Comment: Thanks, @Paulw11, I thought something like triggering `backgorundoperation` and scan, connect, etc.,. Or Create a `Today Widget` when another app wants BLE data and each time update perform action and update `Widget`

Comment: Getting data from a BLE device in the background requires that the device can "push" the data via a notify. You can't really pull data when the app is in the background.  (You could initiate a connection when a new device is discovered/comes into range and download data at that point in time)

Comment: Okay. You saying, While app in background connection establishing is not possible. Then at-least after connection establishment in our application, only background operation for retrieve?

Comment: Read the core Bluetooth programming guide from Apple. When your app is suspended it can do 3 things; 1, Connect to a newly discovered peripheral. 2, Complete a pending connection to a previously discovered peripheral that has just come back into range and 3, receive data that the peripheral has provided via a “notify”. Any of these 3 things will get your app executing in the background. You can then perform other tasks such as connecting to the newly discovered peripheral or reading other characteristics or writing to other characteristics.